# Javascript Assign and delete properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, assign

Can someone explain me what exactly is happening here?

```js
var myObject = {
  price: 20.99,
  get_price: function() {
    return this.price;
  }
};

var customObject = Object.create(myObject);
customObject.price = 19.99;
delete customObject.price;
console.log(customObject.get_price()); //returns 20.99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened due to the consequences of [prototype-chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). The statement

```
var customObject = Object.create(myObject);
```

creates an object with its prototype set as `myObject`. Now you're assigning and deleting the property `price` on it. But it doesn't change what's already there in its prototype.

You can try that by printing `customObject` to the console prior to deleting the property `price`. You will see that the object contains a property `price` with value set as 19.99, but its `__proto__` property's `price` is still 20.99. Run the following snippet, and observe the output in your browser's console.

```js
var myObject = {
  price: 20.99,
  get_price: function() {
    return this.price;
  }
};

var customObject = Object.create(myObject);
customObject.price = 19.99;
console.log(customObject);
```

The function `get_price` returns `this.price`, which searches for a property `price` in the current object, and if not found, it recursively traverses the prototype-chain for this property. Since this property existed in the immediate prototype of the object, the value 20.99 is returned.

Answer (score 2):

All objects in Javascript have a `__proto__` property, which is called its *prototype*. (It's not the same as the `prototype` property on some functions, for reasons that I'll not discuss.)

The *prototype chain* is the order in which some name will be looked for when requested. For example `dog.bark` will search `'bark'` in `dog`, but if `dog` has no `'bark'` property, it will search `'bark'` in `dog.__proto__` and so on, until it reaches the end of the *prototype chain*.

A new object declared using the brackets syntax (`{}`) has `Object` as its prototype.

The function `Object.create(some)` returns a new object which has `some` as its prototype. (`some` can be `null` to create an object without a prototype).

```
var myObject = {
  price: 20.99,
  get_price: function() {
    return this.price;
  }
};
var customObject = Object.create(myObject);
customObject.price = 19.99; // *
delete customObject.price; // **
console.log(customObject.get_price());
```

In ***** the object `customObject` looks like this:

```
customObject = {
  price: 19.99,
  __proto__: {
    price: 29.99,
    get_price: function() { return this.price; }
  }
};
```

In ****** the object `customObject` looks like this:

```
customObject = {
  __proto__: {
    price: 29.99,
    get_price: function() { return this.price; }
  }
};
```

The [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) *only deletes **own** properties*, which means those properties that belong directly to the object (rather than its prototype).

Thus we deleted the `price: 19.99` and now we get `price: 29.99` when we try to get `customObject.price` (which is what `get_price` does).

If we call `myObject.get_price()` we get `myObject.price`, while in `customObject.get_price()` we get `customObject.price`. Although the `get_price` function is actually inside of `customObject.__proto__`, the special variable `this` within a function call refers to the object on which the function was called, rather than the object which the function belongs to.

This makes sense if you think that the same function can belong to different objects.